# solr get total count of specific keyword or phrase in pdf

Tags: pdf, search, solr, search-engine, keyword

I am new to solr and I am trying to get the total number of specific keyword or phrase occurrences in PDF document.

I made a simple installation by downloading `solr-6.0.0.zip`, unziping it, and running `solr-6.0.0/bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt`.

Then I download test pdf file from http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf and posted it to sorl for indexing using the following command:

```
solr-6.0.0/bin/post -c gettingstarted ../pdf-test.pdf
```

This is the result:

```
java -classpath /home/test/solr-6.0.0/dist/solr-core-6.0.0.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=gettingstarted -Ddata=files org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool ../pdf-test.pdf
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file pdf-test.pdf (application/pdf) to [base]/extract
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Time spent: 0:00:04.450
```

When I run simple query for all documents I see that my `pdf-test.pdf` is indexed:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":26,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"/home/test/solr-6.0.0/../pdf-test.pdf",
        "date":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
        "pdf_pdfversion":[1.6],
        "xmp_creatortool":["Acrobat PDFMaker 7.0.7 for Word"],
        "company":["Government of Yukon"],
        "stream_content_type":["application/pdf"],
        "dc_creator":["Yukon",
          "Canada",
          "Yukon Department of Education"],
        "dcterms_created":["2008-06-04T22:44:00Z"],
        "last_modified":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
        "dcterms_modified":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
        "dc_format":["application/pdf; version=1.6"],
        "title":[" PDF Test Page"],
        "last_save_date":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
        "meta_save_date":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
        "pdf_encrypted":[true],
        "dc_title":[" PDF Test Page"],
        "modified":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
        "content_type":["application/pdf"],
        "stream_size":[20597],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser"],
        "creator":["Yukon",
          "Canada",
          "Yukon Department of Education"],
        "meta_author":["Yukon",
          "Canada",
          "Yukon Department of Education"],
        "meta_creation_date":["2008-06-04T22:44:00Z"],
        "created":["Wed Jun 04 22:44:00 UTC 2008"],
        "xmptpg_npages":[1],
        "creation_date":["2008-06-04T22:44:00Z"],
        "resourcename":["/home/test/solr-6.0.0/../pdf-test.pdf"],
        "sourcemodified":["D:20080604224256"],
        "author":["Yukon",
          "Canada",
          "Yukon Department of Education"],
        "producer":["Acrobat Distiller 7.0.5 (Windows)"],
        "_version_":1533019696879632384}]
  }}
```

Now I would like to for example get the total number of occurrences of keyword `PDF`.

I know that there is **4** occurrences of keyword `PDF` inside the `pdf-test.pdf` file.

How can I query in that simple setup to get this result? How should it looks like? Or more generally how to query to get the list of occurrences of keywords or phrase from indexed pdf files?

Comment: Try termvector component

Comment: could you please send sample query which would give me the result? I am trying to understand termvector